# How do you access an httpd.conf Environment variable in .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, environment-variables

This doesnt seem to work in .htacces:

```
SetEnv FOO %{ENV:BASH}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want to do.

In order to pass them to the CGI scripts, you can access the environment variables with `PassEnv`.

With `mod_rewrite`, you can access them with the `%{ENV:blah}` form.

There are no other ways to access the Unix environment variables.

To manipulate Apache environment variables, you may want to check the [documentaton](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html)